# How can I track investments in Mint that aren't on an online account?

Tags: mint.com

I have some investments in some archaic funds that don't have an online tool for Mint to scrape data from.

Is there a way manually to add a symbol and number of shares to Mint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manually add any kind of asset you want. Mint will just store a name and a value that you give it.

1. **+ ADD ACCOUNTS** at the top
2. **Add a property** at the bottom
3. **Other**
4. **Miscellaneous Items** or whatever category you prefer
5. You can put in the symbol and number of shares as the name if you like, and the total value below.
6. **ADD IT**